# Highcharts - How can I put a 100% fix value in the X axis?

Tags: highcharts

How can I put a 100% fix value in the X axis? The idea is that four separate bars add up to 100%. If we don't put a 100% fix value on the X axis the graph takes as maximum value the item with the biggest percentage. See example below. TIA

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srduscea/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max):

```
yAxis: {
   min: 0,
   max: 100,
    title: {
        text: null,
    },
    labels: {
            enabled: false
    }
},
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help.